# Node.js web server app problems

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a Node.js app, using http and httpdispatcher to handle web server requests. I have the following code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    sys = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs'),
    dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');

app.listen(61337);

dispatcher.setStatic('assets');

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }

function handler (request, response) {
    dispatcher.dispatch(request, response);
}

dispatcher.onGet("/", function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        fs.readFile('./assets/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            res.end(data);
        });
});

dispatcher.onGet("/api/update", function(req, res) {
    exec("sh /path/to/update.sh &", puts);

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('1');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    /** Socket.io coming soon */
});
```

I get the following errors.

```
path.js:360
    throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');

TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
at path.js:360:15
at Array.filter (native)
at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
at HttpDispatcher.staticListener (***/httpdispatcher.js:81:39)
at ***/httpdispatcher.js:132:3
at HttpChain.next (***/httpdispatcher.js:125:9)
at doDispatch (***/httpdispatcher.js:58:13)
at HttpDispatcher.dispatch (***/httpdispatcher.js:74:14)
at Server.handler (***/app-server.js:19:13)
at Server.<anonymous> (***/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:369:22)
```

The `Server.handler (***/app-server.js:19:13)` line is `dispatcher.dispatch(request, response);` in the `handler` function.. so I'm not sure why it's not sending strings?

Comment: `httpdispatcher` doesn't seem to be a very widely used or tested module, it's possible the error is due to some issue with its code. You may want to open an issue on its Github page.

Comment: Do you recommend an alternative @Aweary?

Comment: It looks like you're just routing HTTP requests, so I'd recommend Express.js. It's very intuitive and one of the most popular frameworks for Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went from using `httpdispatcher` to `express`

Here is my working example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').createServer(app).listen(61337),
    sys = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    fs = require('fs');

app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        fs.readFile('./assets/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            res.end(data);
        });
});

app.get("/api/update", function(req, res) {
    exec("sh /path/to/update.sh &", puts);

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('1');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

});
```